# Changing this graph equation so it always passes through (1,1)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, linear-transformations, graphing-functions

I need a graph of $y=d*ln(cx+1)$ where $d$ is automatically calculated from $c$ so that it always passes through $(1,1)$.

ie. Like this but where $d$ is calculated automatically from $c$:
[image: Like this, but where d is calculated automatically]

I tried substituting $x=1$, $y=1$ into the equation and solving for $d$, but that just gives me $d=1/ln(cx+1)$ which of course gives a straight line.

What am I missing on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Set $x=1$ also, not just $y=1$

Answer (score 1):

From $$y=d\ln (cx+1)$$

If we let $x=y=1$, then we found the relationship

$$1=d\ln(c+1)$$

or $$d=\frac{1}{\ln(c+1)}$$

Desmos  [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gfqseclhjf) for the graph.

Comment: Thanks. I solved that as well, but then I was stupidly accidentally using d= 1/ln(cx+1) with an x in there which of course wasn't working. My error. Appreciate it.